# Stack data based on substring in column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a bit new to Python and Pandas and I do not understand how to stack data based on part of the column name.

My data looks like below: (part of sample data)

| ID | Region | Rep | Item_Loop1 | Units_A_Loop1 | Type_col_X_Loop1 | Unit_Cost_Type_New_Loop1xyz | Total_Loop1ABCD | Item_Loop2 | Units_A_Loop2 | Type_col_X_Loop2 | Unit_Cost_Type_New_Loop2xyz | Total_Loop2ABCD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Central | Andrews | Pencil | 75 | A | 1,99 | 149,25 | Pencil | 66 | Q | 1,99 | 131,34 |
| 4 | Central | Jardine | Pen Set | 50 | C | 4,99 | 249,5 | Pen Set | 50 | V | 4,99 | 249,5 |
| 5 | East | Jones | Pencil | 95 | B | 1,99 | 189,05 | Binder | 60 | A | 4,99 | 299,4 |
| 6 | Central | Kivell | Binder | 50 | X | 19,99 | 999,5 | Pen Set | 96 | G | 4,99 | 479,04 |

Except first 3 columns (ID, Region, Rep) all other columns contain the same substring "Loop" with number of loop, e.g. loop1, loop2, loop3 --> Item_Loop1, Item_Loop2, Item_Loop3

I need to change this data to the one stacked by ID. So for example for ID = 1 there will be 2 additional rows for each loop:

| ID | Region | Rep | Loop | Item_ | Units_A_ | Type_col_X_ | Unit_Cost_Type_New_xyz | Total_ABCD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Central | Andrews | Loop1 | Pencil | 75 | A | 1,99 | 149,25 |
| 1 | Central | Andrews | Loop2 | Pencil | 66 | Q | 1,99 | 131,34 |
| 1 | Central | Andrews | Loop3 | Pencil | 14 | X | 1,29 | 18,06 |
| 4 | Central | Jardine | Loop1 | Pen Set | 50 | C | 4,99 | 249,5 |
| 4 | Central | Jardine | Loop2 | Pen Set | 50 | V | 4,99 | 249,5 |
| 4 | Central | Jardine | Loop3 | Binder | 11 | Y | 4,99 | 54,89 |
| 5 | East | Jones | Loop1 | Pencil | 95 | B | 1,99 | 189,05 |
| 5 | East | Jones | Loop2 | Binder | 60 | A | 4,99 | 299,4 |
| 5 | East | Jones | Loop3 | Pencil | 35 | Q | 4,99 | 174,65 |
| 5 | East | Jones | Loop4 | Pen Set | 16 | A | 15,99 | 255,84 |
| 5 | East | Jones | Loop5 | Binder | 60 | G | 8,99 | 539,4 |

What I've tried doing us to split columns by *_* and stacking it with 'loop'. The problem that I found was that my columns have multiple *_* in it and after 'loopX' there is additional text. I've tried slicing column names with `rfind`/`slice`, but I couldn't execute reasonable results.

My general idea was more or less:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True) 
#I've tried to use rfind and slicing column name to -> find index of last '_' and get 5 next characters, but I couldn't execute it without errors
df = df.stack(dropna=False).rename_axis(['ID','Region','Rep','Loop']).reset_index()
```

I'm also not sure why in preview tables look good, but when posted it's not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.MultiIndex` to split your columns. `level0` contains `LoopX` while `level1` are the column names without `LoopX`. Replace current index withe the two combined levels and stack level 0.

```
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'Region', 'Rep'])
level0 = df.columns.str.extract(r'(Loop\d+)', expand=False)
level1 = df.columns.str.replace(r'_Loop\d+', '', regex=True)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([level0, level1])
out = df.stack(level=0).reset_index()
```

```
>>> out
   ID   Region      Rep level_3     Item TotalABCD Type_col_X Unit_Cost_Type_Newxyz  Units_A
0   1  Central  Andrews   Loop1   Pencil    149,25          A                  1,99       75
1   1  Central  Andrews   Loop2   Pencil    131,34          Q                  1,99       66
2   4  Central  Jardine   Loop1  Pen Set     249,5          C                  4,99       50
3   4  Central  Jardine   Loop2  Pen Set     249,5          V                  4,99       50
4   5     East    Jones   Loop1   Pencil    189,05          B                  1,99       95
5   5     East    Jones   Loop2   Binder     299,4          A                  4,99       60
6   6  Central   Kivell   Loop1   Binder     999,5          X                 19,99       50
7   6  Central   Kivell   Loop2  Pen Set    479,04          G                  4,99       96
```

Details:

```
>>> level0
Index(['Loop1', 'Loop1', 'Loop1', 'Loop1', 'Loop1',
       'Loop2', 'Loop2', 'Loop2', 'Loop2', 'Loop2'],
      dtype='object')

>>> level1
Index(['Item', 'Units_A', 'Type_col_X', 'Unit_Cost_Type_Newxyz', 'TotalABCD',
       'Item', 'Units_A', 'Type_col_X', 'Unit_Cost_Type_Newxyz', 'TotalABCD'],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2):

Normalize the column names in such a way that each column name starts with the prefix `LoopN_`, then split and expand the col names around the delimiter `_` to create a multiindex columns, then `stack` the frame on `level=0` to reshape

```
df = df.set_index(["ID", 'Region', 'Rep'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'(.*)(Loop\d+)(.*)', r'\2_\1\3')\
                       .str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)
df = df.stack(0)
```

---

```
                            Item_ Total_ABCD Type_col_X_ Unit_Cost_Type_New_xyz  Units_A_
ID Region  Rep                                                                           
1  Central Andrews Loop1   Pencil     149,25           A                   1,99        75
                   Loop2   Pencil     131,34           Q                   1,99        66
4  Central Jardine Loop1  Pen Set      249,5           C                   4,99        50
                   Loop2  Pen Set      249,5           V                   4,99        50
5  East    Jones   Loop1   Pencil     189,05           B                   1,99        95
                   Loop2   Binder      299,4           A                   4,99        60
6  Central Kivell  Loop1   Binder      999,5           X                  19,99        50
                   Loop2  Pen Set     479,04           G                   4,99        96
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(
    r"(.*)_Loop(\d+)(.*)", r"\1_\3_Loop\2", regex=True
)
stubnames = set(c.rsplit("_", maxsplit=1)[0] for c in df.columns if "Loop" in c)
df = (
    pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames, i="ID", j="xxx", sep="_Loop")
    .reset_index()
    .drop(columns="xxx")
    .sort_values(by="ID")
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID   Region      Rep  Units_A Type_col_X Total_ABCD     Item Unit_Cost_Type_New_xyz
0   1  Central  Andrews       75          A     149,25   Pencil                   1,99
4   1  Central  Andrews       66          Q     131,34   Pencil                   1,99
1   4  Central  Jardine       50          C      249,5  Pen Set                   4,99
5   4  Central  Jardine       50          V      249,5  Pen Set                   4,99
2   5     East    Jones       95          B     189,05   Pencil                   1,99
6   5     East    Jones       60          A      299,4   Binder                   4,99
3   6  Central   Kivell       50          X      999,5   Binder                  19,99
7   6  Central   Kivell       96          G     479,04  Pen Set                   4,99
```